# Validity of the copy-swap idiom

Tags: c++, exception

The inherent value of a copy-swap pattern for the `operator =` in a C++ data container is said to arise from

1. Code reuse and
2. Exception safety.

However the copy-swap idiom allocates much more memory than would otherwise be necessary, as data is not destroyed before the copy is created, increasing the chance of exceptions substantially. Given that this is the case, what is the point in claiming that it is a useful pattern?

Are there *any* other cases in which a copy operation could throw (that do not relate to the objects being copied) other than running out of memory?

Comment: Did you just answer your first question already? The points in claiming that it is a useful pattern are: 1. Code reuse and 2. Exception safety.

Comment: The keyword is "trade-off". Want strong guarantee? Pay the price. Want to pay less? Accept a weaker guarantee.

Comment: *"data is not destroyed before the copy is created"* Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but if you destroy the data first, you won't be able to copy it, will you?

Comment: @Mario - You do not destroy the data of the /target/ before you copy the /source/ data.

Answer (score 6):

The copy&swap idiom for the assignment operator yields the strong exception guarantee: the original value is untouched when building a new object would throw. When reusing memory allocated for the assigned to object the strong exception guarantee can typically only be achieved when none of the involved operation may throw. Especially when class templates are involved (as in `std::vector<T>`) there is generally no guarantee that none of the operations throws (of course, `std::vector<T>` only provides the basic exception guarantee upon assignment).

In general, copy assignments can throw for whatever reason. Most likely they shouldn't throw for other reasons than failures to allocate resources but there isn't anything in the CopyAssignable concept which prohibits the operation from throwing.

I found it quite common that copy assignments were not correctly implemented and would, e.g., violate the basic exception guarantee. The indicator that this is the case is when the assignment operator needs to check for self-assignment: if a self-assignment is actually needed (rather than just being there, sometimes defined as an "optimization" - how often do people do self-assignments...?), the code is almost certainly wrong, most likely not maintaining the basic exception guarantee. As a result I recommend using the copy&swap approach unless there is a very good reason not to although I'm aware that it uses more memory (although the problem is rarely that there isn't enough memory, at least not on the systems I'm working on, but rather that use of more memory may result in slower execution).

Comment: What if a class has a buffer allocated with `new []`?  Copying an object would require duplicating the buffer, but the original buffer in the copied-to object would have to be `delete`d.  I don't see how to make this work without a check for self-assignment, but the weak guarantee _can_ be maintained with some care.  Of course, it's possible to hide this behind some other container class (e.g., `std::vector`), but I still disagree with the claim that "if a self-assignment is actually needed ..., the code is almost certainly wrong, most likely not maintaining the basic exception guarantee."

Comment: @JoshuaGreen: if you want to retain the allocated buffer you are pretty much in a world where only the basic exception guarantee can be given. The obvious way for assigning a sequence of objects is to assign them individually. Note that there is no self-assignment check needed: the container simply relies on the constituent object's self-assignment being correct! I have seen a few cases where the self-assignment check was needed and the assignment operator was still correct. However, these are an irrelevant minority: typically a necessary self-assignment check is indicative of an error.

Comment: The case I'm thinking of is when I wanted to `delete` the (old) allocated buffer -- to release any memory in case the copied one is smaller -- and then reallocate it and copy the elements over.  True, that reallocation could be saved if I weren't concerned about giving back unneeded memory.

Comment: @JoshuaGreen: if you allocate new memory, it is even more obvious: you unconditionally allocate new memory, copy the state, and if all is good release the original memory, putting the corresponding pointers into place (the short form to express this behavior is the copy&swap approach). No check for self-assignment is needed for this approach to be semantically correct! The assignment will just be made when it isn't really needed but optimizing for self-assignment is somewhat silly.

Comment: Yes, the copy-swap method is guaranteed to be correct without a self-assignment check, but as the OP notes it (at least temporarily) requires more memory (which may be undesirable) and hence isn't quite the panacea that it's often made out to be.

Comment: @JoshuaGreen, so basically the point is that the source element's copy constructors/operators may also be allocating memory (for example if the type is a class with some internal dynamic memory allocation), if I'm understanding you correctly? How exactly would they throw even in this case, if not for a lack of memory?